# Airflow - ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow, dockeroperator

I am running airflow webserver/scheduler on aws ec2 facing below issue.

This issue occured after pulling docker image from registry

any suggestion or workaround would be helpful.

```
[2020-11-04 01:03:46,192] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 556, in _get_chunk_left
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 523, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 588, in _readinto_chunked
    chunk_left = self._get_chunk_left()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 558, in _get_chunk_left
    raise IncompleteRead(b'')
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: you need to be more specific. What is the command you run before this error appeared?

Comment: @Elad docker operator tried to pull the docker image from registry. 
`
[2020-11-04 01:03:46,121] {docker_operator.py:271} INFO - Extracting
[2020-11-04 01:03:46,138] {docker_operator.py:271} INFO - Downloading
[2020-11-04 01:03:46,192] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)) `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [{taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65074358/taskinstance-py1128-error-connection-broken-incompleteread0-bytes-read)

Comment: @Tamlyn your link doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, the question I linked to has since been deleted. But also it didn't have any answers. I don't remember posting that comment. Am I even me?